# Is ({-2,-1,0,1,2}, +) a group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Let A = {-2,-1,0,1,2}

By definition (A,+) is a group, because:
 1. + is associative
 2. 0 is neutral element 
 3. There exist inverse element for each element in the set.

But after subgroup characterization theorem B is subgroup of A iff f.a. x,y from B x+y in B and x^(-1) in B.
So let B=A, then 
e.g. 1+2=3 which is not in B => B is not a subgroup.

But by def of a subgroup B is a sub group of A iff it forms a group with + itself, which is true.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: How is "+" defined here? Is it addition modulo 5, or regular addition?

Comment: If it’s a group, what is $2+2$?

Answer (score 5):

You say "$1+2=3$ which is not in $B$" but (assuming mod 5 addition) $3$ is the same as $-2$ which is in $B$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

$2+2=?$ or $2+1=?$

can you complete the argument?

Answer (score 0):

The first axiom of a group, tells us, that the set is closed under group operation, meaning:

for group $G$, and $x$, $y$ $\in$ G, it follows $x+y \in G$.

But in your case if you add $1+2$ you get $3$ which is not element of the group $G$, so $G$ is not a group.